# How to create a single file pull request from scratch, and checkout only this single file?

Tags: git

I start with empty directory:

```
git clone --no-checkout <repository> <directory>
```

I have the following parameters:

1. `<remote>` - branch for pull request (not HEAD), e.g. `integration`
2. `<filepath>` - path to file to **update**, e.g. `version.txt`

What should be the next steps?

**Update:**

Finally, the following worked for me:

```
# clone and create local branch named <remote> from <remote>
git clone --no-checkout --branch <remote> <repository> <directory>
cd <directory>

# checkout only one file
git checkout <remote> -- <filepath>

edit <filepath>

# commit only one file
git commit -m <message> -- <filepath>

# push local branch to a new remote branch
git push origin <remote>:refs/heads/<remote>-edit
```

However, this script works only for **one** branch per repository. If more than one branch should be updated this way, some `git reset` is still required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't explicit in your question, so I'm going to assume you're
working with a repository on GitHub.

If you're trying to avoid checking out all the files in a large
repository, it might be easiest to just edit the single file through
the github web ui, since this way you don't need to clone the
repository to your local filesystem.

If that's not an option, then maybe something like this would work:

1. Fork the repository on GitHub
2. Clone your fork of the repository:

   ```
   git clone --no-checkout <repository> <directory>
   ```
3. Change into the working directory:

   ```
   cd <directory>
   ```
4. Reset the repository state (because of the `--no-checkout`, all
   files in the repository will initially be staged for deletion):

   ```
   git reset HEAD
   ```
5. Create a new branch for your work:

   ```
   git checkout -b my-new-feature
   ```
6. Check out the file you want to modify:

   ```
   git checkout HEAD src/main.c
   ```
7. Make your changes:

   ```
   vim src/main.c
   ```
8. Stage those changes for a commit:

   ```
   git add src/main.c
   ```
9. Commit the changes:

   ```
   git commit -m "Add awesome new feature"
   ```
10. Push the changes to the remote repository:

    ```
    git push -u origin HEAD
    ```
11. Make a pull request from that branch to the target branch.

Comment: thanks! Yes, I wasn't explicit enough: 1) It is not GitHub repo 2) I need it fully automatic, so even for GitHub repo web UI is not a solution.

Comment: This is still going to be the correct process. Since you haven't provided any information about the hosting provider (other than "it's not github"), can't help you much on how to automate the creation of the PR. Using GitHub this would be easy using the `gh` cli tool.